# repair suspect database

Tags: sql-server-2008, database

My sql server 2008 told me that you database is suspect and I can't see my tables or my data or use it what should I do ?

Answer (score 4):

Restore.

While this is going on, read [Paul Randal's site](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/TechEd-Demo-Creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database.aspx): he wrote DBCC for Microsoft.

Basically you have a corrupt database: there are several solutions floating around on the internet but restoring from a good backup is usually best.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a complete guide and explanation on how to go with reparing a suspect database, this happend to me several months ago and decided to document what I sepcifially made for those who might need -> http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/reparing-suspect-sql-database/