# repair database

Tags: windows, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [repair suspect database](https://serverfault.com/questions/199138/repair-suspect-database)

my sql server 2008 told me that you database is suspect and I can't see my tables or my data what should I do ?

Comment: Put the database offline and restore from backup. This belongs to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Already asked on SF just now  http://serverfault.com/questions/199138/repair-suspect-database

Answer (score 2):

Restore.

While this is going on, read [Paul Randal's site](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/TechEd-Demo-Creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database.aspx): he wrote DBCC for Microsoft.

Basically you have a corrupt database: there are several solutions floating around on the internet but restoring from a good backup is usually best.

Comment: Seconded. As I commented on @Raymund's answer, you stand a chance of making a database inconsistent if you attempt a repair.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a complete guide and explanation on how to go with reparing a suspect database, this happend to me several months ago and decided to document what I sepcifially made for those who might need -> http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/reparing-suspect-sql-database/

Comment: Since your page includes the `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` command, I think it's important to add a very large disclaimer that there is potential for data loss if you use this.

Comment: @Randolph - Thanks for noting that, I did added your suggestion now

Comment: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/Repair.aspx